# How to transfer custom audience upload data to bigquery?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-ads-api

Q1: In google ads where is the custom data uploaded? In some segment, table  etc?

Q2: Once data is uploaded in google ads how we can transfer that data to big query?

I didn't find anything

Comment: Is there a I can suppress the data in Google ads in custom audience list upload, Is there a way I can dynamically change the data in the list ?